# Openning cmd from website page - php or other option?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, wpf, web

I built a WPF C# application that map drives to the local machine. However, I'm trying to make it on website. Is it possible to do it?
I'm doing it by open cmd with `Process.Start` command in c# in my application.
I read about `exec()` function in PHP, but is it can help to reach my target or I should try something else?

Comment: That is fundamentally impossible.

Comment: PHP is executed on the server, not on the client machine. The browser has no such capabilities on the client machine.

Comment: Well then the only way to make it possible is with application? There is no way to make it work on web site?

Comment: Correct, if it was possible it would be a big security issue if any webpage could run applications on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no you can't do what you want from a web application.

A website runs on a remote server and (rightly) has no control over the machine of the end user who views it. All that happens is the user's browser makes a request to the remote website, and the website returns some HTML (essentially HTML is just text in an agreed format) to display inside the browser. JavaScript code can run to manipulate the structure of the page within the browser, and can send/receive more data from the server.

But for security reasons the JavaScript cannot do anything which changes the state of the end-user's machine. It is caged within the browser environment. It also cannot get much useful info about the user's machine, without the user's explicit, manual consent. Think about if it could - malicious websites (or, arguably worse) malicious code injected into legitimate-looking websites) could steal information from your machine, delete files, map unwanted drives (!), change passwords etc etc - without having to ask your permission. The web would be un-usable for all practical purposes.